# How to parse text structure with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

i want to parse some information in python with beautifulsoup. 
This is the source HTML:

```
<dt class="time">21:07</dt>
<dd class="mix">
  <ul class="item">
    <li class="title">
      <span>John</span>
      <span>Room 1</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</dd>
<dt class="time">21:10</dt>
<dd class="mix">
  <ul class="item">
    <li class="title">
      <span>Susi</span>
      <span>Room 2</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</dd>
....
```

I want to output all in the following way:

```
21:07 John Room 1
21:10 Susi Room 2
```

What i tried until now:

```
page = urlopen(html_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
soup.prettify()
times = soup.find_all('dt', {'class': 'time'})
roominfos = soup.find_all('li', {'class': 'title'})
for time in times:
    print(time.text)
for roominfo in roominfos:
    print(roominfo.text)
```

I only manage to get the time item and the room information seperatly, but not side by side. How could i do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
s = """
<dt class="time">21:07</dt>
<dd class="mix">
<ul class="item">
<li class="title">
<span>John</span>
<span>Room 1</span>
</li>
</ul>
</dd>
<dt class="time">21:10</dt>
<dd class="mix">
<ul class="item">
<li class="title">
<span>Susi</span>
<span>Room 2</span>
</li>
</ul>
</dd>
"""
data = soup(s, 'lxml')
final_data = [i.text for i in data.find_all(re.compile('dt|span'))]
new_final_data = [final_data[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(final_data), 3)]
```

Output:

```
[[u'21:07', u'John', u'Room 1'], [u'21:10', u'Susi', u'Room 2']]
```